# Converting a JSON string to CSV using CSVHelper

Tags: c#, json, csv, csvhelper

I'm working with JSON/CSV files in my ASP.NET Web API project and tried using the [CSVHelper](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper) and [ServiceStack.Text](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text) libraries to generate a CSV, but couldn't make it work.

The JSON file containing an array is dynamic and may have any number of fields.

I read the file using streamreader and then need to convert it into CSV file to make it downloadable for end users.

**example file text**

```
[{"COLUMN1":"a","COLUMN2":"b","COLUMN3":"c","COLUMN4":"d","COLUMN5":"e"},
 {"COLUMN1":"a","COLUMN2":"b","COLUMN3":"c","COLUMN4":"d","COLUMN5":"e"}]
```

**JSON to CSV**

```
public static string jsonStringToCSV(string content)
{
    var jsonContent = (JArray)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content);
    
    var csv = ServiceStack.Text.CsvSerializer.SerializeToCsv(jsonContent);
    return csv;
}
```

This doesn't result me CSV data

[image]

Then some files are of a delimited type with comma or tab, and and I want to utilize [CSVHelper](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper) to convert CSV string to an IEnumerable dynamically.

```
public static IEnumerable StringToList(string data, string delimiter, bool HasHeader)
{
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(new StringReader(data)))
    {
         csv.Configuration.SkipEmptyRecords = true;
         csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = HasHeader;
         csv.Configuration.Delimiter = delimiter;

         var records = csv.GetRecords();
         return records;
     }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean dynamic number of columns in your object, or dynamic number of items in the array?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I was able to solve it by deserializing using `DeserializeObject` to a datatable.

**To convert JSON string to DataTable with [Newtonsoft's Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm):**

```
public static DataTable jsonStringToTable(string jsonContent)
{
    DataTable dt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(jsonContent);
    return dt;
}
```

**To make a CSV string with [CSVHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/):**

```
public static string jsonToCSV(string jsonContent, string delimiter)
{
    StringWriter csvString = new StringWriter();
    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(csvString))
    {
        csv.Configuration.SkipEmptyRecords = true;
        csv.Configuration.WillThrowOnMissingField = false;
        csv.Configuration.Delimiter = delimiter;

        using (var dt = jsonStringToTable(jsonContent))
        {
            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
            {
                csv.WriteField(column.ColumnName);
            }
            csv.NextRecord();

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    csv.WriteField(row[i]);
                }
                csv.NextRecord();
            }
        }
    }
    return csvString.ToString();
}
```

**Final Usage in WebAPI**

```
string csv = jsonToCSV(content, ",");

HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
result.Content = new StringContent(csv);
result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/csv");
result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = "export.csv" };
return result;
```

Comment: Does it work great? My jsonStringToTable crashed due to formatting in the newtonsoft.

Comment: what do you do when you have a Json object as a field? deserializing to DataTable will throw an error

Answer (score 31):

Just in case you want to explore an open-source library to do the job, here is one that I wrote.

Cinchoo ETL makes it easy to convert JSON to CSV with a few lines of code

```
using (var r = new ChoJSONReader("sample.json"))
{
    using (var w = new ChoCSVWriter("sample.csv").WithFirstLineHeader())
    {
        w.Write(r);
    }
}
```

For more information / source, go to https://github.com/Cinchoo/ChoETL

**NuGet package:**

**.NET Framework:**

```
Install-Package ChoETL.JSON
```

**.NET Core:**

```
Install-Package ChoETL.JSON.NETStandard
```

Sample fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/T3u4W2

Full Disclosure: I'm the author of this library.

Comment: understood. FYI, It is an open source library, showing how to accomplish the problem using it. Nothing more than that.

Comment: I understand. I'm just saying how it is perceived by the community. Just include your relation to the library and it should be Ok.

Comment: I installed your `Install-Package ChoETL` and then trying to add its namespace. But system giving me error of **reference missing**. I cleaned solution also but all in vain. Could you help!! @RajN

Comment: Is your project .net framework or .net core? If .net core use ChoETL.JSON.NETStandard package. If .net framework, use ChoETL.JSON

Comment: @RajN getting "Method not found: 'Void ChoETL.ChoRecordReader..ctor(System.Type, Boolean)'." on your package usage.

Comment: Found out the incompatible dependencies in the package. Corrected, pushed new version 1.0.9.

Comment: This library is superb. It unravels even nested levels of json into a csv, capturing all the data.

Comment: @Cinchoo - I appreciate your fast tool but have found that it is missing the ability to escape characters in the json automatically.  Single quotes and commas in a json string throws the error, "Illegal characters in path

Answer (score 7):

Had the same problem recently and I believe there is a little bit more elegant solution using the [System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject?view=netframework-4.8) and [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/). It is less code and hopefully the performance is similar or better compared to the DataTable.

```
    public static string JsonToCsv(string jsonContent, string delimiter)
    {
        var expandos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject[]>(jsonContent);

        using (var writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer))
            {
                csv.Configuration.Delimiter = delimiter;

                csv.WriteRecords(expandos as IEnumerable<dynamic>);
            }

            return writer.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can't get this to work if some entries are missing some of the values

Answer (score 1):

This code is OK for me:

3 functions (check, parse and aux)

```
    private bool IsValidJson(string strInput)
    {
        try 
        { 
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strInput)) { return false; }
        
            strInput = strInput.Trim();

            if ((strInput.StartsWith("{") && strInput.EndsWith("}")) || (strInput.StartsWith("[") && strInput.EndsWith("]"))) 
            {
                try
                {
                    _ = JToken.Parse(strInput);

                    return true;
                }
                catch
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
        catch { throw; }
    }

    private string ParseJsonToCsv(string json)
    {
        try
        {
            XmlNode xml = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode("{records:{record:" + json + "}}");

            XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument(); xmldoc.LoadXml(xml.InnerXml);

            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet(); dataSet.ReadXml(new XmlNodeReader(xmldoc));

            string csv = DTableToCsv(dataSet.Tables[0], ",");

            return csv;
        }
        catch { throw; }
    }

    private string DTableToCsv(DataTable table, string delimator)
    {
        try 
        { 
            var result = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                result.Append(table.Columns[i].ColumnName);
                result.Append(i == table.Columns.Count - 1 ? "\n" : delimator);
            }

            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    result.Append(row[i].ToString());
                    result.Append(i == table.Columns.Count - 1 ? "\n" : delimator);
                }

            return result.ToString().TrimEnd(new char[] { '\r', '\n' });
        }
        catch { throw; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code successfully compiles with latest stable version of CsvHelper nuget package.

```
public static string JsonToCsv(string jsonContent, string delimeter)
        {
            var expandos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject[]>(jsonContent);

            using (TextWriter writer = new StringWriter())
            {
                CsvConfiguration csvConfiguration = new CsvConfiguration(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
                csvConfiguration.Delimiter = delimeter;
                using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, csvConfiguration))
                {
                    csv.WriteRecords((expandos as IEnumerable<dynamic>));
                }

                return writer.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Convert2Json() 
        { 
            try 
            { 
                if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName != string.Empty) 
                { 
                    string[] FileExt = FileUpload1.FileName.Split('.'); 
                    string FileEx = FileExt[FileExt.Length - 1]; 
                    if (FileEx.ToLower() == "csv") 
                    { 
                        string SourcePath = Server.MapPath("Resources//" + FileUpload1.FileName); 
                        FileUpload1.SaveAs(SourcePath); 
                        string Destpath = (Server.MapPath("Resources//" + FileExt[0] + ".json")); 

                        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Destpath); 
                        var csv = new List<string[]>(); 
                        var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(SourcePath); 
                        foreach (string line in lines) 
                            csv.Add(line.Split(',')); 
                        string json = new 
                            System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(csv); 
                        sw.Write(json); 
                        sw.Close(); 
                        TextBox1.Text = Destpath; 
                        MessageBox.Show("File is converted to json."); 
                    } 
                    else 
                    { 
                        MessageBox.Show("Invalid File"); 
                    } 

                } 
                else 
                { 
                    MessageBox.Show("File Not Found."); 
                } 
            } 
            catch (Exception ex) 
            { 
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
            } 
        }
```

Comment: You're using line.Split(',') which is not a good idea. Better to use a csv reader.

Answer (score -3):

```cs
using System.Globalization;

using (var csv = new CsvWriter(csvString, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)) {
  ...
}
```