# C# Convert Json to CSV

Tags: c#, json, csv, choetl

I have a json file in the following format:

```
{
"HDRDTL":["SRNO","STK_IDN","CERTIMG"],
"PKTDTL":[
{"SRNO":"2814","STK_IDN":"1001101259","CERTIMG":"6262941723"},
{"SRNO":"2815","STK_IDN":"1001101269","CERTIMG":"6262941726"},
{"SRNO":"2816","STK_IDN":"1001101279","CERTIMG":"6262941729"}
],
"IMGTTL":
["CERTIMG","ARRIMG"],
"IMGDTL":{"CERTIMG":"CRd6z2uq3gvx7kk","ARRIMG":"ASd6z2uq3gvx7kk"}
}
```

The "PKTDTL" array is the part I need to convert to csv.
How can I achieve this in C# ?

Note, as an example, I only have 3 items in the "PKTDTL", the real json file has thousands of lines of ({"SRNO" ...}) and is huge.

I have written following code which does not work. see error message commented in the code.

**Question**

- Anyone knows why it failed ?
- Do you have a better/alternative method

  ```
  public static void ConvertJsonToCSV(string InFile)
  {

  string OutFile=InFile.Replace("json","csv");

  StreamReader sInFile = new StreamReader(InFile);
  StreamWriter sOutFile = new StreamWriter(OutFile);

  using (sInFile)
  {
      string sJson = sInFile.ReadToEnd();

      //*************************************************************
      // the below line failed, error message: unexpected json token
      // when reading datatable, expected startArray, got StartObject.
      //**************************************************************

      DataTable dt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(sJson);
      //DataTable dt = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(sJson, new { Makes = default(DataTable) }).Makes;

      var sb = new StringBuilder();

      string[] columnNames = (from dc in dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                              select dc.ColumnName).ToArray();

      sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));

      foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
      {
          foreach (object field in dr.ItemArray)
          {
              sb.Append(field.ToString().Replace(",", "") + ",");
          }
          sb.Replace(",", "\n", sb.Length - 1, 1);
      }

      sOutFile.Write(sb.ToString());

      sOutFile.Close();
      sInFile.Close();
  }
  ```

  }

Comment: a big clue to whether you have asked a question or not is if you use a ?  .  This looks like you just need to use the debugger.

Comment: You say it does not work. What does it do?

Comment: Keith: I know where the bug is. it is at the line "DataTable dt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(sJson);" it says: unexpected Json token when reading DataTable. Expected StartArray, got StartObject...

Comment: I guess the line `"IMGDTL":{"CERTIMG":"CRd6z2uq3gvx7kk","ARRIMG":"ASd6z2uq3gvx7kk"}` is the problem. It doesn't contain an array but an object. You need to fix the JSON, or the data source respectively.

Comment: Are you sure the JSON is correct? Because here it says it's incorrect: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: Federico is right, there are 2 commas missing after the first two `}`, although it might be just a copy&paste error here.

Comment: Hi Markus, according to https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp. Json can have object as well as arrays. Besides, the file is download from a vendor website. It is beyond my control to fix the source itself.

Comment: Andrew & Federico, you are correct. I accidentally missed out the comma during copy & paste. I have put them back, Now they pass through  jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com as valid json format. But when running the code, still giving me same error.

Comment: thats because your json isn't suited to be converted into a data table

Comment: I know that JSON can contain objects (that's what it is for after all), the problem ist that the serializer is pretty stupid. I only can do the most simple transformation that fits the data type it is given. It assumes that for a `DeserializeObject<DataTable>` the JSON that is passed only contains arrays. In this case an object is invalid content - not for the JSON but for the Deserializer.

Comment: You can try this, i found this as one of the best approach - https://stackoverflow.com/a/58035299/5714042

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL.JSON/) - an open source library, you can do do the conversion easily with few lines of code

```
string json = @"{
    ""HDRDTL"":[""SRNO"",""STK_IDN"",""CERTIMG""],
    ""PKTDTL"":[
    {""SRNO"":""2814"",""STK_IDN"":""1001101259"",""CERTIMG"":""6262941723""},
    {""SRNO"":""2815"",""STK_IDN"":""1001101269"",""CERTIMG"":""6262941726""},
    {""SRNO"":""2816"",""STK_IDN"":""1001101279"",""CERTIMG"":""6262941729""}
    ],
    ""IMGTTL"":
    [""CERTIMG"",""ARRIMG""],
    ""IMGDTL"":{""CERTIMG"":""CRd6z2uq3gvx7kk"",""ARRIMG"":""ASd6z2uq3gvx7kk""}
    }";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
using (var p = ChoJSONReader.LoadText(json).WithJSONPath("$..PKTDTL")
    )
{
    using (var w = new ChoCSVWriter(sb)
        .WithFirstLineHeader()
        )
        w.Write(p);
}

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Output:

```
SRNO,STK_IDN,CERTIMG
2814,1001101259,6262941723
2815,1001101269,6262941726
2816,1001101279,6262941729
```

Checkout CodeProject article for some additional help.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this library.

Comment: The library worked great. Question: what does the $ followed by 2 dots mean in: "$..PKTDTL". also do you have documentation on the syntax of using your methods?

Comment: It is JSON path. Refer this link for more info http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/

Comment: if the values contains special character, e.g. DEP%, the output replaced them into underscore, becomes DEP_. Is there anyway to fix it?

Comment: I’m not able to reproduce it. What version of the lib are you using in your project? Pls try with latest and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I found myself in similar situation. this is what i did. first I created a JObject (using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq) let us consider that your json is in a string variable called "strJSON".

```
 JObject jsonObj= JObject.parse(strJSON);
 JObject  PKTDL=jsonObj["PKTDTL"] as JObject;
 IList<string> keys = PKTDL.Properties().Select(p => p.Name).ToList(); // this gives column names
 StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
 string headers="";
 foreach(string key in keys)
 {
   headers+=","+key;
 }  
 sb.AppendLine(headers.TrimStart(','));
 foreach(JObject j in jsonObj["PKTDTL"]) //if jobject doesnt work try "JToken j"
 {
    string values="";
    foreach(string key in keys)
    {
       values+=","+jsonObj["PKTDTL"][key];
    }
    sb.AppendLine(values.TrimStart(','));
 }

   File.WriteAllText(filePath, sb.ToString());
```

then save sb as a csv

Comment: Error on line 2, 'JToken' does not contain a definition for 'Properties' and the best extension method overload 'Extensions.Properties(IEnumerable<JObject>)' requires a receiver of type. Any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: edited. casted jsonObj["PKTDTL"] to jobject before using proerties

Answer (score 0):

Similar question to [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36274948/538435) (see the JsonToCsv(string, string) method there). If you are already using [NewtonSoft Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) and [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) you can do similar conversion with the help of [ExpandoObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject?view=netframework-4.8).

```
    var jsonText = @"{
        ""HDRDTL"":[""SRNO"",""STK_IDN"",""CERTIMG""],
        ""PKTDTL"":[
        {""SRNO"":""2814"",""STK_IDN"":""1001101259"",""CERTIMG"":""6262941723""},
        {""SRNO"":""2815"",""STK_IDN"":""1001101269"",""CERTIMG"":""6262941726""},
        {""SRNO"":""2816"",""STK_IDN"":""1001101279"",""CERTIMG"":""6262941729""}
        ],
        ""IMGTTL"":
        [""CERTIMG"",""ARRIMG""],
        ""IMGDTL"":{""CERTIMG"":""CRd6z2uq3gvx7kk"",""ARRIMG"":""ASd6z2uq3gvx7kk""}
        }";

    var jtoken = JObject.Parse(jsonText).SelectToken("$..PKTDTL");
    var expandos = jtoken.ToObject<ExpandoObject[]>();
    string csvText;

    using (var writer = new StringWriter())
    {
        using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer))
        {
            csv.WriteRecords(expandos as IEnumerable<dynamic>);
        }

        csvText = writer.ToString();
    }

    Console.WriteLine(csvText);
```