# Get json data from url and output as a csv file

Tags: c#, json, rest

How can you get JSON data dynamically, then output it as a CSV file? Is it possible to get it to output with a change in data?

I have the following code below, but it doesn't work.

```
var url = "https://reqres.in//api/users?page=2";

using (WebClient webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
  WebClient n = new WebClient();
  var json = n.DownloadString(url);
  string valueOriginal = Convert.ToString(json);
}
```

I want to get the JSON data from whatever URL and output it as a CSV.

Comment: Could you show us your json format and expect csv format?

Comment: Are you passing `"apiURL"` as a parameter instead of the actual `url` property?

Comment: @D-Shih https://reqres.in//api/users?page=2

Comment: @IpsitGaur my bad edited the url

Comment: *Is it possible to get it output with a change in data*, well, you will need to define the csv structure.. there is [no free lunch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_free_lunch_theorem) for the conversion, [whoops](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv).

Comment: Json is the serialisation of an object. Csv isn't. So you create the class for serialisation and voila

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/2.x/)? One example can be found from [here](https://tech.io/playgrounds/5197/writing-csv-files-using-c).

Another option is to write your own implementation to achieve this goal (as shown in [example1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36274948/json-string-to-csv-and-csv-to-json-conversion-in-c-sharp) or [example2](http://www.w3spark.com/asp-net/reading-and-writing-csv-files-in-asp-net-using-c-using-csvhelper-nuget-package/)).

Good luck.