# How to transform Azure Search query result into a table / spreadsheet format

Tags: json, azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-blob-storage

I use blob storage to save data from my Botframework v4 Chatbot.

When I query the results with Azure Search I get this:

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://roboadvisorydatasearch.search.windows.net/indexes('azureblob-index')/$metadata#docs(*)",
"value": [
    {
        "@search.score": 1,
        "content": "{\"id\":\"3470100\",\"realId\":\"3470100\",\"document\":{\"name\":\"pierre\",\"age\":18,\"gender\":\"weiblich\",\"education\":\"Abitur\",\"complete\":true,\"roundCounter\":1,\"riskchoices\":[\"B\"],\"riskAssessmentComplete\":true,\"riskDescription\":\"höchst risikoliebend\",\"order\":[\"0\",\"2\",\"1\"],\"choice\":\"Plus GmbH\",\"follow\":true,\"endRepeat\":true,\"eTag\":\"\\\"0x8D6AB012AE82E05\\\"\",\"loss1\":\"ACG GmbH\",\"win1\":\"Plus GmbH\",\"win2\":\"Breen GmbH\",\"payout\":\"Du bekommst 7000 Geldeinheiten = 7,00€ ausgezahlt.\"}}\n"
    },
    {
        "@search.score": 1,
        "content": "{\"id\":\"159287\",\"realId\":\"159287\",\"document\":{\"name\":\"A18\",\"age\":18,\"gender\":\"weiblich\",\"education\":\"Abitur\",\"complete\":true,\"roundCounter\":7,\"riskchoices\":[\"A\",\"A\",\"A\",\"A\",\"A\",\"A\",\"B\"],\"riskAssessmentComplete\":true,\"riskDescription\":\"risikoavers\",\"order\":[\"1\",\"2\",\"0\"],\"choice\":\"ACG GmbH\",\"follow\":false,\"endRepeat\":true,\"eTag\":\"\\\"0x8D6A94E40672463\\\"\",\"win1\":\"Breen GmbH\",\"win2\":\"Plus GmbH\",\"loss2\":\"ACG GmbH\",\"payout\":\"Du bekommst 5000 Geldeinheiten = 5,00€ ausgezahlt.\"}}\n"
    }
]
}
```

What I want is a table / spreadsheet (that I can use in Excel for example). Each result should be in a row and the colums should be the keys from the JSON inside each "content". This [website](https://json-csv.com/) works great, but only if I insert the object inside "content". But doing this for each row would be a lot of work.

Answer (score 1):

Our API does not support returning results in csv format. You need to convert response by yourself.

Sample solution for C#: [JSON string to CSV and CSV to JSON conversion in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36274948/json-string-to-csv-and-csv-to-json-conversion-in-c-sharp)

Sample solution for JavaScript: [How to convert JSON to CSV format and store in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847766/how-to-convert-json-to-csv-format-and-store-in-a-variable)