# c# convert json string to .csv

Tags: c#, json, csv, choetl

I am trying to convert a json string, containing array elements, to a .csv file.  Below is the json string format:

```
{"inputFile": [["Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4", "Column5", "Column6", "Column7", "Column8", "Column9", "Column10"], ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"], ["K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T"]]}
```

solved.  Thanks heyNow.

```
            dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
            var rowElements = new List<string>();

            foreach (var data in dynObj.inputFile)
            {
                var row = new List<string>();
                foreach (var dataItem in data)
                {
                    var item = Convert.ToString(dataItem);
                    row.Add(item);
                }

                rowElements.Add( String.Join(",", row)+"\n");
            }
            var CSV = String.Join("",rowElements);
            Console.WriteLine(CSV);

For RaJN:
Updated code to replace json file path to json string:

        StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();
        using (var p = ChoJSONReader.LoadText(jsonString)
            .WithJSONPath("$.inputFile[*]")
            )
        {
            using (var w = new ChoCSVWriter(msg))
            {
                w.Write(p);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(msg.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: First telling us you had no luck doesn't mean anything to anyone, secondly deserialising a json string is one of the most commonly asked question on stackoverflow for C#, what did you research and why didn't it work?

Comment: You say: "With no luck".... That doesn't help us. What error do you get!!! We can't help you this way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try with newtonsoft jsonparser.
If you can get your JSON as a string..

```
dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);

string CSV = "";

foreach (var data in dynObj.inputFile)
{
    List<string> row = new List<string>();

    foreach(var dataItem in data)
    {
        row.Add(dataItem);
    }

    CSV+=string.Join(row, ",");
}
```

You will get 1 giant string containing all the values as a CSV. 
Let us know if this is what you want.

Comment: Thanks heyNow.  Updated the code to make it work for me:
`dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
            var rowElements = new List<string>();
            foreach (var data in dynObj.inputFile)
            {
                var row = new List<string>();
                foreach (var dataItem in data)
                {
                    var item = Convert.ToString(dataItem);
                    row.Add(item);
                }

                rowElements.Add( String.Join(",", row)+"\n");
            }
            var CSV = String.Join("",rowElements);
`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can generate CSV from your JSON file using [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL.JSON/)

```
        StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();
        using (var p = new ChoJSONReader("*** YOUR JSON FILE PATH ***")
            .WithJSONPath("$.inputFile[*]")
            )
        {
            using (var w = new ChoCSVWriter(msg))
            {
                w.Write(p);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(msg.ToString());
        }
```

Output:

```
Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4,Column5,Column6,Column7,Column8,Column9,Column10
A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J
K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T
```

**UPDATE:**

```
            string json = @"
{
  ""inputFile"": [
    [""Column1"", ""Column2"", ""Column3"", ""Column4"", ""Column5"", ""Column6"", ""Column7"", ""Column8"", ""Column9"", ""Column10""],
    [ ""A"", ""B"", ""C"", ""D"", ""E"", ""F"", ""G"", ""H"", ""I"", ""J"" ],
    [ ""K"", ""L"", ""M"", ""N"", ""O"", ""P"", ""Q"", ""R"", ""S"", ""T"" ]
  ]
}";

            StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();
            using (var p = ChoJSONReader.LoadText(json)
                .WithJSONPath("$.inputFile[*]")
                )
            {
                using (var w = new ChoCSVWriter(msg))
                {
                    w.Write(p);
                }
                Console.WriteLine(msg.ToString());
            }
```

Comment: I tried it again, but it was giving me a 

`Failed to assign 'System.Object[]' fallback value to 'Value' field.`

One thing I changed from your code was instead of passing in a json file path, i wanted to pass in a json string.

`using(var p = ChoJsonReader.LoadText(jsonString).WithJSONPath("$.inputFile[*]))`

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce error. Edit your question and add your code there.

Comment: @Cinchoo as [discussed previously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44889944/2325377) you should disclose your relationship to the library when promoting your own code as a solution to others.