# Azure Search: Export Results to CSV

Tags: html, azure, azure-search-.net-sdk

Just wondering, would it be possible to extract my search results to CSV? Maybe placing a button on the html body to extract the info. Thank you.

My search results are defined as below.

```
const resultTemplate = `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-9"><h4>{{request_type}}</h4><div class="resultDescription">{{{user_name}}}</div></div>`;
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no ready to use code for it, you'll need to extract the json from your Azure Search Service and generate the csv from it.

Here's a sample of how to extract all documents from your Azure Search (JSON):

https://github.com/liamca/azure-search-backup-restore

Here's how to convert JSON to CSV:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36348017/1384539