# Import JSON data into a table using excel VSTO webaddin c#

Tags: c#, json, excel, vsto, office-addins

I want to get data from this api and import data into a excel sheet using c#

and also want to convert that jasonContent1 to csv format.
thank you..

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    string url = String.Format("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users?id=1");
    WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);

    webRequest.Method = "GET";
    HttpWebResponse respObj = null;
    respObj = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();

    string resultTest1 = null;
    using (Stream stream = respObj.GetResponseStream())
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        resultTest1 = reader.ReadToEnd();
        //string json = resultTest1.Trim();
        // DataSet jsonContent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(json);
        var jsonContent1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(resultTest1);


        reader.Close();

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to run the code under the debugger? What values do you see?

Comment: "[\n  {\n    \"id\": 1,\n    \"name\": \"Leanne Graham\",\n    \"username\": \"Bret\",\n    \"email\": \"Sincere@april.biz\",\n    \"address\": {\n      \"street\": \"Kulas Light\",\n      \"suite\": \"Apt. 556\",\n      \"city\": \"Gwenborough\",\n      \"zipcode\": \"92998-3874\",\n      \"geo\": {\n        \"lat\": \"-37.3159\",\n        \"lng\": \"81.1496\"\n      }\n    },\n    \"phone\": \"1-770-736-8031 x56442\",\n    \"website\": \"hildegard.org\",\n    \"company\": {\n      \"name\": \"Romaguera-Crona\",\n      \"catchPhrase\": \"Multi-layered client-server neural-net\",\n

Comment: See [JSON string to CSV and CSV to JSON conversion in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36274948/json-string-to-csv-and-csv-to-json-conversion-in-c-sharp)